# How to compare the schema of a dataframe read from an RDBMS table against the same table on Hive?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I created a dataframe by reading an RDBMS table from postgres as below:

```
  val yearDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", connectionUrl)
                         .option("dbtable", s"(${execQuery}) as year2017")
                         .option("user", devUserName)
                         .option("password", devPassword)
                         .option("numPartitions",10)
                         .load()
```

`execQuery` content: `select qtd_balance_text,ytd_balance_text,del_flag,source_system_name,period_year from dbname.hrtable;`

This is the schema of my final dataframe:

```
println(yearDF.schema)

StructType(StructField(qtd_balance_text,StringType,true), StructField(ytd_balance_text,StringType,true), StructField(del_flag,IntegerType,true), StructField(source_system_name,StringType,true), StructField(period_year,DecimalType(15,0),true))
```

There is a table on Hive with same name: `hrtable` and same column names. Before ingesting the data into the Hive table, I want to keep a check in the code to see if the schema of GP & Hive tables are same.
I was able to access the schema as following:

```
spark.sql("desc formatted databasename.hrtable").collect.foreach(println)
```

But the problem is it collects the schema in a different way

```
[  qtd_balance_text,bigint,null]
[  ytd_balance_text,string,null]
[          del_flag,string,null]
[source_system_name,bigint,null]
[       period_year,bigint,null]
[Type,MANAGED,]
[Provider,hive,]
[Table Properties,[orc.stripe.size=536870912, transient_lastDdlTime=1523914516, last_modified_time=1523914516, last_modified_by=username, orc.compress.size=268435456, orc.compress=ZLIB, serialization.null.format=null],]
[Location,hdfs://devenv/apps/hive/warehouse/databasename.db/hrtable,]
[Serde Library,org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde,]
[InputFormat,org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat,]
[OutputFormat,org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat,]
[Storage Properties,[serialization.format=1],]
[Partition Provider,Catalog,]
```

Clearly I cannot the schemas which are present in this way and I couldn't understand how to do it.
Could anyone let me know how to properly compare the schema of dataframe `yearDF` and the hive table: `hrtable`?

Comment: What is the result if you read a single line from `hrtable`? Are the schemas comparable then?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parsing of the Hive tables schema output, you can try this option.

Read Hive table also as dataframe. Assume this dataframe is `df1` and your `yearDF`  as `df2`. Then compare schemas as below.

If there is a possibility of column count also differs between two dataframes, then keep additional `df1.size == df2.size` comparison `if` loop also.

```
val x = df1.schema.sortBy(x => x.name) // get dataframe 1 schema and sort it base on column name.
val y = df2.schema.sortBy(x => x.name) // // get dataframe 2 schema and sort it base on column name.

val out = x.zip(y).filter(x => x._1 != x._2) // zipping 1st column of df1, df2 ...2nd column of df1,df2 and so on for all columns and their datatypes. And filtering if any mismatch is there

if(out.size == 0) { // size of `out` should be 0 if matching
    println("matching")
}
else println("not matching")
```